# Are scalings of disjoint balls in $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\{0\}$ still disjoint?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $x,y\in S^{n-1}$ are distinct points. If I put $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}\min\{\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert,\left\Vert x+y\right\Vert\}$ and form the balls $B(x,\epsilon),B(y,\epsilon)\subset \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$. Are the scalings of these ball still disjoint? I.e for $\lambda,\beta\in \mathbb{R}^+$ does $B(\beta\cdot y,\beta \cdot \epsilon)\cap B(\lambda \cdot x,\lambda \cdot \epsilon)=\emptyset$ hold for any choice of $\lambda,\beta \in \mathbb{R}^+$? My intuition tells me that the union of the scalings of such a ball is a cone in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, and that the two cones created by the balls should be disjoint. However I haven't been able to show that it's true.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the purpose of including $\|x+y\|$ in your definition of $\epsilon$? So, for example, if $y=-x$, then $\epsilon = 0$.

Comment: You should remove $||x+y||$ from the definition of $\epsilon$. You should also state that the balls are open. As a hint: First, work out the case of $n=2$ by drawing a picture and verifying that the bisecting line of the pair $x, y$ separates the scaled balls.

Answer (score 1):

Suppos $a,b\in S$ are distinct and $r=|b-a|/2.$ Then the open balls $B(a,r),B(b,r)$ are disjoint. Let $m$ be the midpoint of $[a,b],$ i.e., $m=(a+b)/2.$ Observe that the hyperplane $P=\{x:x\cdot(b-a)=0\}$ is tangent to both $\partial B(a,r),\partial B(b,r)$ at $m.$

Set $H_-=\{x:x\cdot(b-a)<0\},$ $H_+=\{x:x\cdot(b-a)>0\}.$ These are disjoint open half spaces, with $B(a,r)\subset H^-,$ $B(b,r)\subset H_+.$ Now these half spaces are cones in their own right, relative to $0$ as vertex. Thus any positive scalings of $B(a,r),B(b,r)$ will stay in $H^-,H_+$ respectively. This is the desired result.